# Determining appropriate register when POPing value from stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack

I'm learning more about assembly language, and I see instructions like:

```
PUSH EAX;
POP ESP;
```

...which apparently pushes EAX onto the stack, and pops it back into the ESP register.

Are values tagged with the source register in some way on the stack?  For example, is there some way of knowing that the value of EAX that ends up on the stack came from EAX?

If the value of EAX is incompatible with the ESP register, and it gets POPed into ESP, what happens?

Comment: No, not tagged. The value is always "compatible", it's just 32 bits. You might get a fault later if you try to use it.

Comment: There could be any number of reasons for a sequence that pushes one register and immediately pops to another. It is, for example, one way to copy the value from the first register to the second. In the example you cite, it would be just as easily done by `mov esp, eax`. Or it could be an error in judgment on the part of the programmer who wrote the program you're looking at. Hard to say without any further context. But values on the stack, or anyplace else in memory for that matter, have no special tags. They're just values.

Comment: @Jester if you post that as an answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

You must have a strange idea of 'the stack' actually is. `esp` -- the stack pointer -- points somewhere in the regular computer memory. A `push` operation decreases the value of `esp` by 4 and stores its argument value at that address. A `pop` does the reverse. As the stack pointer points to regular memory, values 'on' it *have* no interpretation, other than the usual interpretation of any value in memory.

In your example, what 'value' of EAX may be 'incompatible'? Since ESP is a register as any other, it can hold any value. The only thing is, it may not be safe to read from it (directly, or with a `pop`) or write to it (directly, or with a `push`) - but in that, it is nothing else than treating any other register value as a pointer and attempting to read or write from it.